# How do i call a snowflake procedure from Spark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-connection

I have successfully connected to the snowflake from spark but could not execute call procedure other than select.

Please find the code i used below:

```py
df = spark.read.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME) \
  .options(**sfOptions) \
  .option("query",  call <procedure>) \
  .load()
```

I'm referring to the guide of snowflake - https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is currently possible based on what I understand from  the details put here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32014

Comment: Thanks a lot, by any chance do you know other methods to call the stored procedures?